# Downgrade python dependencies for cloud host

Tags: python-3.x, flask, virtualenv, pythonanywhere

I created a Flask app with python3.10.4 and I want to deploy it on PythonAnywhere which can only handle up to python3.8.

Is there an easy/efficient/professional way to downgrade the entire `requirements.txt` to fit PythonAnywhere's tolerance?

For example, how would I know PythonAnywhere's tolerable dependencies for any of these?

```
APScheduler==3.10.1
blinker==1.6.2
certifi==2023.5.7
charset-normalizer==3.1.0
click==8.1.3
exceptiongroup==1.1.1
Flask==2.3.2
Flask-APScheduler==1.12.4
idna==3.4
iniconfig==2.0.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
markdown-it-py==2.2.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
mdurl==0.1.2
packaging==23.1
pluggy==1.0.0
Pygments==2.15.1
pytest==7.3.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
requests==2.31.0
requests-mock==1.10.0
rich==13.4.1
six==1.16.0
tomli==2.0.1
tzlocal==5.0.1
urllib3==2.0.2
Werkzeug==2.3.4
```

Since if I downgrade python, I have to downgrade flask, and its sub-dependencies, but downgrading sub-dependencies might interfere with other newer libraries relying on it.
I am using `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PythonAnywhere can currently run versions of Python up to 3.10.5.  If you're only seeing versions up to 3.8 in your account, it's probably because your account is an old one with an older system image (essentially the version of the operating system that your code runs on).  You can update your system image to a more recent one on the "Account" page inside PythonAnywhere; there is also [a help page with hints and tips on how to do that](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ChangingSystemImage).